# Data Driven Framework in Android testing using sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, data-driven-tests

I am implementing a data-driven framework to test Android app. The test database is sqlite. I was able to access the database successfully. I tried to parametrize my test case so that i can run test data as an  individual test. 
But as class extends ActivityInstrumentationTestcase2 does not permit us to add parametrize constructor in it.

I want to use `@RunWith` (`Parametrized.class`) class and want to make a function (`@Parameters`) which provides the test data. I also need every test to run as independent test. How can I accomplish this?

Can anyone help me out?